# как добавить target_feature и включить поддержку avx2 в языке rust?

Tags: компиляция, rust

Пишу для себя реализацию игры в жизнь, хочу использовать инструкции avx2 для ускорения вычислений, однако не могу понять, как включить поддержку avx2.
Беру пример из документации:

```rust
#[cfg(
    all(
        any(target_arch = "x86", target_arch = "x86_64"),
        target_feature = "avx2"
    )
)]
fn foo() {
    #[cfg(target_arch = "x86")]
    use std::arch::x86::_mm256_add_epi64;
    #[cfg(target_arch = "x86_64")]
    use std::arch::x86_64::_mm256_add_epi64;

    unsafe {
        //_mm256_add_epi64(...); // Мой код будет допустим здесь
    }
}
```

Однако rust-analyzer выдает вот такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И при компиляции данная функция просто не генерируется. Как добавить `targer_feature`=`avx2`?

Текущая конфигурация `rustc cfg` выглядит так:

```bash
PS C:\Users\artur\rustProjects\life> rustc --print=cfg        
debug_assertions
panic="unwind"
target_arch="x86_64"
target_endian="little"
target_env="gnu"
target_family="windows"
target_feature="fxsr"
target_feature="sse"
target_feature="sse2"
target_has_atomic="16"
target_has_atomic="32"
target_has_atomic="64"
target_has_atomic="8"
target_has_atomic="ptr"
target_os="windows"
target_pointer_width="64"
target_vendor="pc"
windows
```

А текущий target триплет это `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`

**Как мне включить возможность использования avx2 для моего проекта?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Добавил в `.cargo/config.toml`:

**.cargo/config.toml**

```
[build]
rustflags = "-C target-feature=+avx2,+avx"
target = ["x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"]
```

**Так же важно:** нужный мне функционал работает только в nightly версии `rust`. Поэтому пришлось перейти на нее.

`target` Пришлось указать, потому что после перехода в nightly `rust` вместо `gnu` проект начал компилироваться на `msvc`, вместо `MinGW`, так что пришлось указать целевой триплет в `config.toml`